# AMP Server Publish Ready False

Tags: elasticsearch, apm, elastic-apm

I have Multiple applications on my local machine dotnet, python, nodejs and i want to ingest their data into elastic search using apm stand alone agent but em unable to send the data.

elasticsearch.yml
#----------------------- BEGIN SECURITY AUTO CONFIGURATION -----------------------
#
# The following settings, TLS certificates, and keys have been automatically
# generated to configure Elasticsearch security features on 12-09-2023 12:17:38
#
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
# Enable security features
xpack.security.enabled: true

xpack.security.enrollment.enabled: true

# Enable encryption for HTTP API client connections, such as Kibana, Logstash, and Agents
xpack.security.http.ssl:
enabled: true
keystore.path: certs/http.p12

# Enable encryption and mutual authentication between cluster nodes
xpack.security.transport.ssl:
  enabled: true
  verification_mode: certificate
keystore.path: certs/transport.p12
truststore.path: certs/transport.p12
# Create a new cluster with the current node only
# Additional nodes can still join the cluster later
cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["sami-Alienware-Area-51m"]

# Allow HTTP API connections from anywhere
# Connections are encrypted and require user authentication
http.host: "0.0.0.0"

# Allow other nodes to join the cluster from anywhere
# Connections are encrypted and mutually authenticated
#transport.host: 0.0.0.0

#----------------------- END SECURITY AUTO CONFIGURATION -------------------------
```

Unfortunately, APM Server is not working: "publish_ready": false,

```
{
 "build_date": "2023-09-14T12:04:41+01:00",
 "build_sha": "71a546823d31c0360140129e647a0d4e10e944c7",
 "publish_ready": false,
 "version": "8.10.1"
}
```

apm-server's stack trace

> Sep 13 13:31:25 sami-Alienware-Area-51m systemd[1]: Started Elastic APM Server.
>  Sep 13 13:31:25 sami-Alienware-Area-51m apm-server[38983]: {"log.level":"info","@timestamp":"2023-09-13T13:31:25.558+0300","log.origin":{"file.name":"beatcmd/beat.go","file.line":139},"message":"Home pat>
>  Sep 13 13:31:25 sami-Alienware-Area-51m apm-server[38983]: {"log.level":"info","@timestamp":"2023-09-13T13:31:25.560+0300","log.origin":{"file.name":"beatcmd/beat.go","file.line":146},"message":"Beat ID:>
>  Sep 13 13:31:25 sami-Alienware-Area-51m apm-server[38983]: {"log.level":"info","@timestamp":"2023-09-13T13:31:25.561+0300","log.logger":"beat","log.origin":{"file.name":"beatcmd/beat.go","file.line":576}>
>  Sep 13 13:31:25 sami-Alienware-Area-51m apm-server[38983]: {"log.level":"info","@timestamp":"2023-09-13T13:31:25.561+0300","log.logger":"beat","log.origin":{"file.name":"beatcmd/beat.go","file.line":584}>
>  Sep 13 13:31:25 sami-Alienware-Area-51m apm-server[38983]: {"log.level":"info","@timestamp":"2023-09-13T13:31:25.561+0300","log.logger":"beat","log.origin":{"file.name":"beatcmd/beat.go","file.line":587}>
>  Sep 13 13:31:25 sami-Alienware-Area-51m apm-server[38983]: {"log.level":"info","@timestamp":"2023-09-13T13:31:25.561+0300","log.origin":{"file.name":"beatcmd/maxprocs.go","file.line":68},"message":"maxpr>
>  Sep 13 13:31:25 sami-Alienware-Area-51m apm-server[38983]: {"log.level":"info","@timestamp":"2023-09-13T13:31:25.562+0300","log.logger":"beat","log.origin":{"file.name":"beatcmd/beat.go","file.line":591}>
>  Sep 13 13:31:25 sami-Alienware-Area-51m apm-server[38983]: {"log.level":"info","@timestamp":"2023-09-13T13:31:25.562+0300","log.logger":"beat","log.origin":{"file.name":"beatcmd/beat.go","file.line":620}>
>  Sep 13 13:31:25 sami-Alienware-Area-51m apm-server[38983]: {"log.level":"info","@timestamp":"2023-09-13T13:31:25.562+0300","log.logger":"config","log.origin":{"file.name":"config/agentconfig.go","file.li>
>  Sep 13 13:31:25 sami-Alienware-Area-51m apm-server[38983]: {"log.level":"info","@timestamp":"2023-09-13T13:31:25.563+0300","log.origin":{"file.name":"beatcmd/beat.go","file.line":390},"message":"apm-serv>
>  Sep 13 13:31:25 sami-Alienware-Area-51m apm-server[38983]: Error: listen tcp 127.0.0.1:8200: bind: address already in use
>  Sep 13 13:31:25 sami-Alienware-Area-51m apm-server[38983]: Usage:
>  Sep 13 13:31:25 sami-Alienware-Area-51m apm-server[38983]:   apm-server [flags]
>  Sep 13 13:31:25 sami-Alienware-Area-51m apm-server[38983]:   apm-server [command]
>  Sep 13 13:31:25 sami-Alienware-Area-51m apm-server[38983]: Available Commands:
>  Sep 13 13:31:25 sami-Alienware-Area-51m apm-server[38983]:   apikey      Manage API Keys for communication between APM agents and server (deprecated)
>  Sep 13 13:31:25 sami-Alienware-Area-51m apm-server[38983]:   export      Export current config
>  Sep 13 13:31:25 sami-Alienware-Area-51m apm-server[38983]:   help        Help about any command
>  Sep 13 13:31:25 sami-Alienware-Area-51m apm-server[38983]:   keystore    Manage secrets keystore
>  Sep 13 13:31:25 sami-Alienware-Area-51m apm-server[38983]:   run         Run APM Server
>  Sep 13 13:31:25 sami-Alienware-Area-51m apm-server[38983]:   test        Test config
>  Sep 13 13:31:25 sami-Alienware-Area-51m apm-server[38983]:   version     Show current version info
>  Sep 13 13:31:25 sami-Alienware-Area-51m apm-server[38983]: Flags:
>  Sep 13 13:31:25 sami-Alienware-Area-51m apm-server[38983]:   -E, --E setting=value      Configuration overwrite
>  Sep 13 13:31:25 sami-Alienware-Area-51m apm-server[38983]:   -N, --N                    Disable actual publishing for testing
>  Sep 13 13:31:25 sami-Alienware-Area-51m apm-server[38983]:   -c, --c string             Configuration file, relative to path.config (default "apm-server.yml")
>  Sep 13 13:31:25 sami-Alienware-Area-51m apm-server[38983]:       --cpuprofile string    Write cpu profile to file
>  Sep 13 13:31:25 sami-Alienware-Area-51m apm-server[38983]:   -d, --d stringArray        Enable certain debug selectors
>  Sep 13 13:31:25 sami-Alienware-Area-51m apm-server[38983]:   -e, --e                    Log to stderr and disable syslog/file output
>  Sep 13 13:31:25 sami-Alienware-Area-51m apm-server[38983]:       --environment string   Set the environment in which the process is running (default "default")
>  Sep 13 13:31:25 sami-Alienware-Area-51m apm-server[38983]:   -h, --help                 help for apm-server
>  Sep 13 13:31:25 sami-Alienware-Area-51m apm-server[38983]:       --httpprof string      Start pprof http server
>  Sep 13 13:31:25 sami-Alienware-Area-51m apm-server[38983]:       --memprofile string    Write memory profile to this file
>  Sep 13 13:31:25 sami-Alienware-Area-51m apm-server[38983]:       --path.config string   Configuration path (default "")
>  Sep 13 13:31:25 sami-Alienware-Area-51m apm-server[38983]:       --path.data string     Data path (default "")
>  Sep 13 13:31:25 sami-Alienware-Area-51m apm-server[38983]:       --path.home string     Home path (default "")
>  Sep 13 13:31:25 sami-Alienware-Area-51m apm-server[38983]:       --path.logs string     Logs path (default "")
>  Sep 13 13:31:25 sami-Alienware-Area-51m apm-server[38983]:       --strict.perms         Strict permission checking on config files (default true)
>  Sep 13 13:31:25 sami-Alienware-Area-51m apm-server[38983]:   -v, --v                    Log at INFO level
>  Sep 13 13:31:25 sami-Alienware-Area-51m apm-server[38983]: Use "apm-server [command] --help" for more information about a command.
>  Sep 13 13:31:25 sami-Alienware-Area-51m systemd[1]: apm-server.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
>  Sep 13 13:31:25 sami-Alienware-Area-51m systemd[1]: apm-server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
>  Sep 13 13:31:25 sami-Alienware-Area-51m systemd[1]: apm-server.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 1.
>  Sep 13 13:31:25 sami-Alienware-Area-51m systemd[1]: Stopped Elastic APM Server.
>  Sep 13 13:31:25 sami-Alienware-Area-51m systemd[1]: Started Elastic APM Server.
>  Sep 13 13:31:25 sami-Alienware-Area-51m apm-server[38993]: {"log.level":"info","@timestamp":"2023-09-13T13:31:25.726+0300","log.origin":{"file.name":"beatcmd/beat.go","file.line":139},"message":"Home pat>
>  Sep 13 13:31:25 sami-Alienware-Area-51m apm-server[38993]: {"log.level":"info","@timestamp":"2023-09-13T13:31:25.726+0300","log.origin":{"file.name":"beatcmd/beat.go","file.line":146},"message":"Beat ID:>
>  Sep 13 13:31:25 sami-Alienware-Area-51m apm-server[38993]: {"log.level":"info","@timestamp":"2023-09-13T13:31:25.726+0300","log.logger":"beat","log.origin":{"file.name":"beatcmd/beat.go","file.line":576}>
>  Sep 13 13:31:25 sami-Alienware-Area-51m apm-server[38993]: {"log.level":"info","@timestamp":"2023-09-13T13:31:25.726+0300","log.logger":"beat","log.origin":{"file.name":"beatcmd/beat.go","file.line":584}>
>  Sep 13 13:31:25 sami-Alienware-Area-51m apm-server[38993]: {"log.level":"info","@timestamp":"2023-09-13T13:31:25.726+0300","log.logger":"beat","log.origin":{"file.name":"beatcmd/beat.go","file.line":587}>
>  Sep 13 13:31:25 sami-Alienware-Area-51m apm-server[38993]: {"log.level":"info","@timestamp":"2023-09-13T13:31:25.726+0300","log.origin":{"file.name":"beatcmd/maxprocs.go","file.line":68},"message":"maxpr>
>  Sep 13 13:31:25 sami-Alienware-Area-51m apm-server[38993]: {"log.level":"info","@timestamp":"2023-09-13T13:31:25.727+0300","log.logger":"beat","log.origin":{"file.name":"beatcmd/beat.go","file.line":591}>
>  Sep 13 13:31:25 sami-Alienware-Area-51m apm-server[38993]: {"log.level":"info","@timestamp":"2023-09-13T13:31:25.727+0300","log.logger":"beat","log.origin":{"file.name":"beatcmd/beat.go","file.line":620}>
>  ...skipping...
>  Sep 28 12:48:22 sami-Alienware-Area-51m apm-server[42347]: {"log.level":"error","@timestamp":"2023-09-28T12:48:22.732+0300","log.logger":"agentcfg","log.origin":{"file.name":"agentcfg/elasticsearch.go",">
>  Sep 28 12:48:30 sami-Alienware-Area-51m apm-server[42347]: {"log.level":"error","@timestamp":"2023-09-28T12:48:30.764+0300","log.logger":"beater","log.origin":{"file.name":"beater/waitready.go","file.lin>
>  Sep 28 12:48:45 sami-Alienware-Area-51m apm-server[42347]: {"log.level":"error","@timestamp":"2023-09-28T12:48:45.800+0300","log.logger":"beater","log.origin":{"file.name":"beater/waitready.go","file.lin>
>  Sep 28 12:48:52 sami-Alienware-Area-51m apm-server[42347]: {"log.level":"error","@timestamp":"2023-09-28T12:48:52.739+0300","log.logger":"agentcfg","log.origin":{"file.name":"agentcfg/elasticsearch.go",">
>  Sep 28 12:49:00 sami-Alienware-Area-51m apm-server[42347]: {"log.level":"error","@timestamp":"2023-09-28T12:49:00.841+0300","log.logger":"beater","log.origin":{"file.name":"beater/waitready.go","file.lin>
>  Sep 28 12:49:15 sami-Alienware-Area-51m apm-server[42347]: {"log.level":"error","@timestamp":"2023-09-28T12:49:15.876+0300","log.logger":"beater","log.origin":{"file.name":"beater/waitready.go","file.lin>
>  Sep 28 12:49:22 sami-Alienware-Area-51m apm-server[42347]: {"log.level":"error","@timestamp":"2023-09-28T12:49:22.731+0300","log.logger":"agentcfg","log.origin":{"file.name":"agentcfg/elasticsearch.go",">
>  Sep 28 12:49:30 sami-Alienware-Area-51m apm-server[42347]: {"log.level":"error","@timestamp":"2023-09-28T12:49:30.916+0300","log.logger":"beater","log.origin":{"file.name":"beater/waitready.go","file.lin>
>  Sep 28 12:49:45 sami-Alienware-Area-51m apm-server[42347]: {"log.level":"error","@timestamp":"2023-09-28T12:49:45.950+0300","log.logger":"beater","log.origin":{"file.name":"beater/waitready.go","file.lin>
>  Sep 28 12:49:52 sami-Alienware-Area-51m apm-server[42347]: {"log.level":"error","@timestamp":"2023-09-28T12:49:52.733+0300","log.logger":"agentcfg","log.origin":{"file.name":"agentcfg/elasticsearch.go",">
>  Sep 28 12:50:00 sami-Alienware-Area-51m apm-server[42347]: {"log.level":"error","@timestamp":"2023-09-28T12:50:00.984+0300","log.logger":"beater","log.origin":{"file.name":"beater/waitready.go","file.lin>
>  Sep 28 12:50:16 sami-Alienware-Area-51m apm-server[42347]: {"log.level":"error","@timestamp":"2023-09-28T12:50:16.019+0300","log.logger":"beater","log.origin":{"file.name":"beater/waitready.go","file.lin>
>  Sep 28 12:50:22 sami-Alienware-Area-51m apm-server[42347]: {"log.level":"error","@timestamp":"2023-09-28T12:50:22.732+0300","log.logger":"agentcfg","log.origin":{"file.name":"agentcfg/elasticsearch.go",">
>  Sep 28 12:50:31 sami-Alienware-Area-51m apm-server[42347]: {"log.level":"error","@timestamp":"2023-09-28T12:50:31.052+0300","log.logger":"beater","log.origin":{"file.name":"beater/waitready.go","file.lin>
>  Sep 28 12:50:46 sami-Alienware-Area-51m apm-server[42347]: {"log.level":"error","@timestamp":"2023-09-28T12:50:46.084+0300","log.logger":"beater","log.origin":{"file.name":"beater/waitready.go","file.lin>
>  Sep 28 12:50:52 sami-Alienware-Area-51m apm-server[42347]: {"log.level":"error","@timestamp":"2023-09-28T12:50:52.732+0300","log.logger":"agentcfg","log.origin":{"file.name":"agentcfg/elasticsearch.go",">
>  Sep 28 12:51:01 sami-Alienware-Area-51m apm-server[42347]: {"log.level":"error","@timestamp":"2023-09-28T12:51:01.116+0300","log.logger":"beater","log.origin":{"file.name":"beater/waitready.go","file.lin>
>  Sep 28 12:51:16 sami-Alienware-Area-51m apm-server[42347]: {"log.level":"error","@timestamp":"2023-09-28T12:51:16.168+0300","log.logger":"beater","log.origin":{"file.name":"beater/waitready.go","file.lin>
>  Sep 28 12:51:22 sami-Alienware-Area-51m apm-server[42347]: {"log.level":"error","@timestamp":"2023-09-28T12:51:22.731+0300","log.logger":"agentcfg","log.origin":{"file.name":"agentcfg/elasticsearch.go",">
>  Sep 28 12:51:31 sami-Alienware-Area-51m apm-server[42347]: {"log.level":"error","@timestamp":"2023-09-28T12:51:31.201+0300","log.logger":"beater","log.origin":{"file.name":"beater/waitready.go","file.lin>
>  Sep 28 12:51:46 sami-Alienware-Area-51m apm-server[42347]: {"log.level":"error","@timestamp":"2023-09-28T12:51:46.236+0300","log.logger":"beater","log.origin":{"file.name":"beater/waitready.go","file.lin>
>  Sep 28 12:51:52 sami-Alienware-Area-51m apm-server[42347]: {"log.level":"error","@timestamp":"2023-09-28T12:51:52.731+0300","log.logger":"agentcfg","log.origin":{"file.name":"agentcfg/elasticsearch.go",">
>  Sep 28 12:52:01 sami-Alienware-Area-51m apm-server[42347]: {"log.level":"error","@timestamp":"2023-09-28T12:52:01.270+0300","log.logger":"beater","log.origin":{"file.name":"beater/waitready.go","file.lin>
>  Sep 28 12:52:16 sami-Alienware-Area-51m apm-server[42347]: {"log.level":"error","@timestamp":"2023-09-28T12:52:16.304+0300","log.logger":"beater","log.origin":{"file.name":"beater/waitready.go","file.lin>
>  Sep 28 12:52:22 sami-Alienware-Area-51m apm-server[42347]: {"log.level":"error","@timestamp":"2023-09-28T12:52:22.739+0300","log.logger":"agentcfg","log.origin":{"file.name":"agentcfg/elasticsearch.go",">
>  Sep 28 12:52:31 sami-Alienware-Area-51m apm-server[42347]: {"log.level":"error","@timestamp":"2023-09-28T12:52:31.339+0300","log.logger":"beater","log.origin":{"file.name":"beater/waitready.go","file.lin>
>  Sep 28 12:52:46 sami-Alienware-Area-51m apm-server[42347]: {"log.level":"error","@timestamp":"2023-09-28T12:52:46.375+0300","log.logger":"beater","log.origin":{"file.name":"beater/waitready.go","file.lin>
>  Sep 28 12:52:52 sami-Alienware-Area-51m apm-server[42347]: {"log.level":"error","@timestamp":"2023-09-28T12:52:52.732+0300","log.logger":"agentcfg","log.origin":{"file.name":"agentcfg/elasticsearch.go",">
>  Sep 28 12:53:01 sami-Alienware-Area-51m apm-server[42347]: {"log.level":"error","@timestamp":"2023-09-28T12:53:01.408+0300","log.logger":"beater","log.origin":{"file.name":"beater/waitready.go","file.lin>
>  Sep 28 12:53:16 sami-Alienware-Area-51m apm-server[42347]: {"log.level":"error","@timestamp":"2023-09-28T12:53:16.453+0300","log.logger":"beater","log.origin":{"file.name":"beater/waitready.go","file.lin>
>  Sep 28 12:53:22 sami-Alienware-Area-51m apm-server[42347]: {"log.level":"error","@timestamp":"2023-09-28T12:53:22.732+0300","log.logger":"agentcfg","log.origin":{"file.name":"agentcfg/elasticsearch.go",">
>  Sep 28 12:53:31 sami-Alienware-Area-51m apm-server[42347]: {"log.level":"error","@timestamp":"2023-09-28T12:53:31.497+0300","log.logger":"beater","log.origin":{"file.name":"beater/waitready.go","file.lin>
>  Sep 28 12:53:46 sami-Alienware-Area-51m apm-server[42347]: {"log.level":"error","@timestamp":"2023-09-28T12:53:46.532+0300","log.logger":"beater","log.origin":{"file.name":"beater/waitready.go","file.lin>
>  Sep 28 12:53:52 sami-Alienware-Area-51m apm-server[42347]: {"log.level":"error","@timestamp":"2023-09-28T12:53:52.733+0300","log.logger":"agentcfg","log.origin":{"file.name":"agentcfg/elasticsearch.go",">
>  Sep 28 12:54:01 sami-Alienware-Area-51m apm-server[42347]: {"log.level":"error","@timestamp":"2023-09-28T12:54:01.566+0300","log.logger":"beater","log.origin":{"file.name":"beater/waitready.go","file.lin>
>  Sep 28 12:54:16 sami-Alienware-Area-51m apm-server[42347]: {"log.level":"error","@timestamp":"2023-09-28T12:54:16.602+0300","log.logger":"beater","log.origin":{"file.name":"beater/waitready.go","file.lin>
>  Sep 28 12:54:22 sami-Alienware-Area-51m apm-server[42347]: {"log.level":"error","@timestamp":"2023-09-28T12:54:22.732+0300","log.logger":"agentcfg","log.origin":{"file.name":"agentcfg/elasticsearch.go",">
>  Sep 28 12:54:31 sami-Alienware-Area-51m apm-server[42347]: {"log.level":"error","@timestamp":"2023-09-28T12:54:31.636+0300","log.logger":"beater","log.origin":{"file.name":"beater/waitready.go","file.lin>
>  Sep 28 12:54:46 sami-Alienware-Area-51m apm-server[42347]: {"log.level":"error","@timestamp":"2023-09-28T12:54:46.670+0300","log.logger":"beater","log.origin":{"file.name":"beater/waitready.go","file.lin>
>  Sep 28 12:54:52 sami-Alienware-Area-51m apm-server[42347]: {"log.level":"error","@timestamp":"2023-09-28T12:54:52.732+0300","log.logger":"agentcfg","log.origin":{"file.name":"agentcfg/elasticsearch.go",">
>  Sep 28 12:55:01 sami-Alienware-Area-51m apm-server[42347]: {"log.level":"error","@timestamp":"2023-09-28T12:55:01.712+0300","log.logger":"beater","log.origin":{"file.name":"beater/waitready.go","file.lin>
>  Sep 28 12:55:16 sami-Alienware-Area-51m apm-server[42347]: {"log.level":"error","@timestamp":"2023-09-28T12:55:16.752+0300","log.logger":"beater","log.origin":{"file.name":"beater/waitready.go","file.lin>
>  Sep 28 12:55:22 sami-Alienware-Area-51m apm-server[42347]: {"log.level":"error","@timestamp":"2023-09-28T12:55:22.741+0300","log.logger":"agentcfg","log.origin":{"file.name":"agentcfg/elasticsearch.go",">
>  Sep 28 12:55:31 sami-Alienware-Area-51m apm-server[42347]: {"log.level":"error","@timestamp":"2023-09-28T12:55:31.796+0300","log.logger":"beater","log.origin":{"file.name":"beater/waitready.go","file.lin>
>  Sep 28 12:55:46 sami-Alienware-Area-51m apm-server[42347]: {"log.level":"error","@timestamp":"2023-09-28T12:55:46.840+0300","log.logger":"beater","log.origin":{"file.name":"beater/waitready.go","file.lin>
>  Sep 28 12:55:52 sami-Alienware-Area-51m apm-server[42347]: {"log.level":"error","@timestamp":"2023-09-28T12:55:52.731+0300","log.logger":"agentcfg","log.origin":{"file.name":"agentcfg/elasticsearch.go",">
>  Sep 28 12:56:01 sami-Alienware-Area-51m apm-server[42347]: {"log.level":"error","@timestamp":"2023-09-28T12:56:01.874+0300","log.logger":"beater","log.origin":{"file.name":"beater/waitready.go","file.lin>
>  Sep 28 12:56:16 sami-Alienware-Area-51m apm-server[42347]: {"log.level":"error","@timestamp":"2023-09-28T12:56:16.908+0300","log.logger":"beater","log.origin":{"file.name":"beater/waitready.go","file.lin>
>  Sep 28 12:56:22 sami-Alienware-Area-51m apm-server[42347]: {"log.level":"error","@timestamp":"2023-09-28T12:56:22.731+0300","log.logger":"agentcfg","log.origin":{"file.name":"agentcfg/elasticsearch.go",">
>  Sep 28 12:56:31 sami-Alienware-Area-51m apm-server[42347]: {"log.level":"error","@timestamp":"2023-09-28T12:56:31.944+0300","log.logger":"beater","log.origin":{"file.name":"beater/waitready.go","file.lin>
>  Sep 28 12:56:46 sami-Alienware-Area-51m apm-server[42347]: {"log.level":"error","@timestamp":"2023-09-28T12:56:46.979+0300","log.logger":"beater","log.origin":{"file.name":"beater/waitready.go","file.lin>
>  Sep 28 12:56:52 sami-Alienware-Area-51m apm-server[42347]: {"log.level":"error","@timestamp":"2023-09-28T12:56:52.731+0300","log.logger":"agentcfg","log.origin":{"file.name":"agentcfg/elasticsearch.go",">
>  Sep 28 12:57:02 sami-Alienware-Area-51m apm-server[42347]: {"log.level":"error","@timestamp":"2023-09-28T12:57:02.012+0300","log.logger":"beater","log.origin":{"file.name":"beater/waitready.go","file.lin>
>  Sep 28 12:57:17 sami-Alienware-Area-51m apm-server[42347]: {"log.level":"error","@timestamp":"2023-09-28T12:57:17.057+0300","log.logger":"beater","log.origin":{"file.name":"beater/waitready.go","file.lin>
>  lines 18516-18569/18569 (END)

i want to be able to collect metric data from apps and rum data as well for my web apps.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.